# Java EE using Datasource without lookup method

Tags: java, datasource, code-injection, web.xml

I'm trying to use a Datasource (Database) in my program using JNDI. I got it to work partially but not like I want it to work.
I want to inject the JNDI Resource, but it does not work properly.

It does not work, if I use the annotation.

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/crmv1")
DataSource ds;
```

But it does work, when I use the lookup method:

```
try {
        ds = InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/crmv1");
    } catch (NamingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to use the annotation. I'm pretty sure, that I have to set something in the web.xml, but I don't know what. I tried to google it, but I'm not really sure what searchterms to use.

Comment: Which app/webserver and version?

Comment: Is your class a container-managed class, such as an EJB or JSF managed bean?

Comment: I'm using glassfish 4.1. My class is a normal class, normally instantiated by a JSF backing bean. No EJB involved.

Comment: I'm an iditot. I was so worried about not using the consturctor in injected objects, that I forgot I can use it in a normally instanciated class. I can just use the lookup method in the constructor.Can it be, that I can't use injection in normally instanciated classes? That would be a huge problem for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Resource annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) you can try using the lookup element instead of the name and use the jndi-name you configured in your application server.

Example-
If it is mapped with the jndi-name "jdbc/crmv1" try      `@Resource(lookup="dbc/crmv1")` or `@Resource(lookup="java:jdbc/crmv1")`

The only relation to the web.xml is that you use a deployment descriptor to override the resource mapping that you specify in an annotation.

Comment: I tried both your lookup suggestions (without changing anything else). It still does not work. When I use the lookup mehod of InitalContext it works, but if I only use the annotation it does not. I should mention, that the error occurs after the class is instantiated, I get a NullPointerException when I try to use the DataSource.

Comment: The cause of the problem was, that I instantiated the class with new, when I inject the class it works. Is there a way to use injection in POJOs? I would like to use @SessionScoped objects in the class, but dolookup does nor work on these objects.

Comment: You mean you annotated the resource and then you overwrote it? And what do you want to inject in a POJO?

Comment: Within a backingbean of a JSF, I want to instanciate a normal POJO via the keyword 'new'. In that POJO I would like to inject @SessionScoped beans. When I try that, the state of the variable is null.

Comment: I don't think you can call it a POJO anymore after that. More details are required in order to answer such a question. I advise you ask a new one for that.